# How to fetch data row by row from mysql table, queries coded in php, using jquery (AJAX)?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am a beginner in Ajax. I want to fetch data row from Subject Table consist of only one column Subject as varchar(100), defined in MySQL DB. Following is my php code.

Data.php

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("","root","root","DBTemp") or die("</br> Error: " .mysqli_connect_error());

$sql="select * from Subject";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
    echo $row["SUBJECT"];
    //I Want This Value to Be received in my Jquery Page
    //So that i can take certain action based on each Subject.
    //For example creating a select box child elements,options.
 }
?>
```

Jquery.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
    var response='';
    $("body").ready(function()
     {
       $.ajax(
          {
            url: '/Data.php',
            type: 'GET'
            success: function(text)
                {
                     response=text;
                }
          });
     });
    $("body").append("<select> /*Get values here as options*/ </select>");
 });
```

But The Desired action is getting values row by row like:-
1st row value comes-> take certain action in jquery;
2nd row value comes-> take sertain action..;
.
.
so on.

Comment: So,where is your Ajax request???

Comment: @Mr.NaViD.. Oh Sorry Sir My Mistake. Let Me Include That....

Comment: instead of using `append()` out side of Ajax success,try using it inside your Ajax success

Comment: @Mr.NaViD... Sir, I Tried that, it is accepting whole table as one option....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data.php

```
<?php

$con=@mysqli_connect("","root","root","DBTemp");

# Instead of that use header 500 to let javascript side know there is a real error.

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Could not connect to database : ". mysqli_connect_error();
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
    exit();
}


$sql="select * from Subject";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (mysqli_error($con))
{
    echo "Query failed : ".mysqli_error($con);
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
    exit();
}

$options = array();

# populate options arrey with using table's id field as key 
# and subject field as value.

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $options[$row['id']] = $row['subject'];

}

# return json encoded array to parse from javascript.
echo json_encode($options);
```

Data.php will output :

```
{"1":"Subject ID 1","2":"Subject ID 3"}
```

Jquery.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("body").ready(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '/Data.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',  // Let jQuery know returned data is json.
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        $.each(result, function(id, subject) {
                            # Loop through results and add an option to select box.
                            $("#ajaxpopulate").append( new Option(subject,id) )
                        });

                    }
                });
    });

});
```

Page.html , inside the body. This select box will populated from ajax request.

```
 <select id="ajaxpopulate"></select>
```

Comment: Thank You Sir. Thats the answer i wanted.

Comment: Sir, What if, I want to remove all the value (received from json array) if fond already exist in select box?

Comment: you can loop through selectbox options with : `$('#ajaxpopulate').each(function(){});` and if it is already exists you can just continue.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to use data structure like an array and pass it as a json response to your ajax call. 
2) You need to iterate through your json array and that is where you can process each row separately and create nested select options.

UPDATE

```
$con=mysqli_connect("","root","root","DBTemp") or die("</br> Error: " 
.mysqli_connect_error());
$sql="select * from Subject";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$jsonResult = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$jsonResult[] = $row["SUBJECT"];
}
echo json_encode($jsonResult);
```

An jquery should look like this

```
$(document).ready(function()

{
var response='';
$("body").ready(function()
 {
   $.ajax(
      {
        url: '/Data.php',
        type: 'GET'
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success: function(data)
            {
                 //Alert should return an array of your subjects
                 //If it does then you need to iterate through this array and create options manually.
                 alert(data);
            }
      });
 });
$("body").append("<select> /*Get values here as options*/ </select>");
```

});

Comment: Sir, Can you give me a sample code so that i can undersand properly. Thank You

Comment: Sir, What if, I want to remove all the value (received from json array) if fond already exist in select box?

Answer (score 0):

I would have the php function return a json response. You could do this in two ways either construct the JSON manually through your while statement server side or use the `json_encode` PHP function and echo that server side. That way when the data is returned client side in your ajax response you can parse the JSON data to a JSON object `JSON.parse(json);` and then control row by row the data in a structured way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sir, What if, I want to remove all the value (received from json array) if fond already exist in select box?

Comment: I am sure you can do the necessary checks in the front end for that or even better you could do the checks in the backend if they already exist.